# Can Malay or Indonesian ever have an /n/ followed by a /g/?

Tags: phonology, orthography, malay

Malay and Indonesian are considered to be very phonetically spelled with the usually cited exception being that orthographic "e" can represent either `/e/` or `/ə/`.

In both orthographies the sound `/ŋ/` is represented with the digraph "ng".

But is it guaranteed that every case of orthographic "ng" is pronounced as `/ŋ/` or are there cases, assumedly at syllable edges, where orthographic "ng" is actually `/ng/`?

(I know `/ŋg/` is possible and is spelled "ngg". Also I believe there are a bunch of sandhi/assimilation rules involving nasals, but I haven't learned those yet.)

Comment: It's virtually universal in all languages that have or can produce clusters of `nasal+stop` that the nasals assimilate to the position of articulation of the stop. In English, if you were to say "A dozen oysters make me feel too full, but the first ten go down easily enough", how likely is it that the /n/ in _ten_ would in fact be pronounced [ŋ]? If you're a native speaker, it would be hard **not** to assimilate it; it would sound strange if you didn't, and might draw attention to the carefulness of the articulation. As for Bahasa, I never heard the cluster /nɡ/, but I'm not native.

Comment: True but we (English native speakers) all can do it effortlessly too if we want to "enunciate clearly" etc. I would even bet there are some silly prescriptive types that would "correct" people to pronounce them separately and not be "lazy". Anyway I don't want to extend rules of my own language to other languages just based on them seeming pretty sensible or universal since languages are so full of much more counterintuitive morsels. Hence I ask ye the experts (-:

Comment: Actually, in normal speech, it seems likely that _first ten go_ in that sentence above wouldn't even have a nasal consonant, but rather would express it by nasalizing the /ɛ/ in ['fɚstʰɛ̧ɡoʷ]. Fæspitʃrulzarfən.

Comment: A good question, though.  I'd imagine if it does happen, it only happens across morpheme boundaries.  In Spanish, there is a single unwritable word, because it has a syllable that ends with an *l*, and another that begins with an *l*, both heard distinctly in speech (*sal* + *le*).  But *ll* is/was a separate letter and has a separate sound.  In English *th* and *sh* are digraphs, but when one syllable ends with *t/s* and the next begins with *h*, you just have to recognize the morphemes (*pothead*, *posthumous*, etc).

Comment: @guifa: Interesting! But I can't find this *salle*? Not an inflected form of *sallar* then?

Comment: It's the verb *salir* in the informal singular imperative *sal*, followed by the indirect object pronoun *le*.

Comment: @jlawler Definitely not for Russian. in Russian /ng/ never becomes [ŋ]. There is no ŋ sound in Russian at all.

Comment: @Anixx. How do you pronounce Англия? I hear [-ŋg-].

Comment: @fdb default pronounciation is [ng], [-ŋg-] if someone wants to imitate foreign accent.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I think a general/universal question and a Russian question could easily be split off this one even.

Comment: FWIW, Finnish has both /ŋ/ and /ng/ (in loanwords), and they're both spelled "ng".  And yes, this causes confusion and inconsistency: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_orthography#Velar_nasal

Comment: I have noticed that both "nk" and "ngk" occur in Malay spelling. I wonder if the former is pronounced `/ŋk/` as per @jlawler 's overservations. If both spellings exist and are pronounced alike this would be a potential source of spelling mistakes and less-than-phonetic spelling (along with "e" &rarr; `/e/` vs `/ə/`). Or if "nk" is pronounced `/nk/` that would suggest `/ng/` is also possible.

Comment: I believe, much to what has already been said, that /ng/ doesn't occur within the syllables of a single word. It does, as Guifa suspects, occur across morpheme boundaries, e.g. "pin gugur" [pin gugo], and that's only if the words are carefully pronounced. Otherwise, the /n/ would assimilate and become /ŋ/ - [piŋgugo]. Can you give examples of words with <nk>? I can't think of any at the moment. Native speaker of Bahasa here, by the way.